# Author of the song Yom Simcha L'Yisrael

Tags: song-poetry, authorship, simchat-torah

Who is the author of the Simchas Torah song [Yom Simcha l'Yisrael](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C)?

Answer (score 1):

Its author is unknown. According to Rabbi Reuven Ochanah in one of his letters to [Rabbi Moshe Buton](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8_(%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%91_%D7%A2%D7%AA)#%D7%97%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D) on the subject of the song ([here](http://asif.co.il/download/kitvey-et/yarhon/hocher-33/30.pdf), pg. 5), he heard from [Rabbi Moshe Tzedakah](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%A6%D7%93%D7%A7%D7%94) that the song was composed by a God-fearing man from the beit midrash "Beit Aharon", whom he (Rabbi Tzedakah) knew.

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=56703&st=&pgnum=310

Answer (score -1):

According to [rotter.net](http://rotter.net/forum/torah/15674.shtml) the composer of this song was Rabbi Ovadya Yosef Zatzal.

Comment: It says he one time ad lib-ed a couple verses into the song, not that he wrote it.

Comment: @DoubleAA: It says השיר הסודי שחיבר הגר"ע יוסף נגד הערבים. I do not see anywhere that it says he one time ad lib-ed a couple verses into the song.

Comment: It gives a couple lines with variant and overtly modern phrases and then says "Here is the original."

Comment: According to comment #8, 20, 28 [here](http://www.kikar.co.il/%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99-%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%A3-%D7%94%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%A2-%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%93-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C.html) he didn't compose it, it's much older.

Comment: And [Shituf Piyut](http://shituf.piyut.org.il/node/9482) claims it's author is unknown.